# How to sum 8 rows at a time in a select statement

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a select statement that gives a set of rows whose count is always a multiple of 8.

What I want to do is to find the sum of the first 8 rows, the second 8 rows and so on. Is there a way to do this

Comment: Just a clarify .... so the output you need will look like this (comma is a row): `1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,8,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,16` ???

Comment: For example, if I I have rownumbers 1 to 24 so the output I'm looking for is Sum of 1 to 8,sum of 9 to 16 and sum of 17 to 24.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
select a from test;

select r/8, SUM(a) from (select ROW_NUMBER() over (order by a)-1 as r,a from test) tab group by r/8;
```

[image]

```
update test set a=t2.v
from test t1,(select (ROW_NUMBER() over (order by a)-1)/8 as v,a from test) as t2
where t1.a=t2.a;
```

[image]

Comment: If I had to update rows in a similar way, say first 8 rows have a column that will have a value 'Set 1' the next 8 with 'Set 2' and so on... will that be possible?

Answer (score 0):

Ideal: You declare `groups of  8 rows` by geting `row number` of all rows, subtract by 1 then divine by 8 . Then you calculate sum of those group that you just declare

Assume that your original query is

```
select col1, col2, ..., value1, value2,... 
from table 
order by col1, col3,...
```

You could use this:

```
select number_group, sum(value1) , sum(value2)
from (
    select (row_number() over (order by col1, col3,...) - 1)/8 number_group,
        t.* 
    from table t
) tmp
group by number_group;
```

Answer (score 0):

I have an idea... but require nested queries:

```
SELECT rn,COUNT(i)
FROM(
SELECT CAST(ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY i) / 8 AS INT) AS rn,i FROM @Tb 
) AS t2
GROUP BY rn
```

First select will give each 8 rows a number, while the second 1 count them

Answer (score 0):

What you are looking for is integer devision.

Ineteger division returns whole numbers only discarding decimal part of the result. This property allows it to be used to place numbers into groups.

### Aggregation

```
SELECT MIN( RowNumber ) AS FirstRow, MAX( RowNumber ) AS LastRow, SUM( value ) AS Total
FROM Table
GROUP BY (( CAST( RowNumber AS INT ) - 1 ) / 8 ) -- uses integer division, discarding decimals
```

It will give the following result:

```
1, 8, sum
9, 16, sum
```

### Window Function

```
SELECT RowNumber, SUM( Value ) OVER( PARTITION BY (( CAST( RowNumber AS INT ) - 1 ) / 8 ))
FROM Table
```

This will give:

```
1, sum( 1 - 8 )
2, sum( 1 - 8 )
...
9, sum( 9 - 16 )
```